# Convert Infragistics UltraGridRow to DataRow

Tags: c#, infragistics, datarow, ultrawingrid

Is there an easy way to convert an infragistics `UltraGridRow` to a standard `DataRow` object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have set the DataSource of your UltraGrid to a DataTable then you could extract the underlying DataRow of the current ActiveRow using

```
 if(grid.ActiveRow != null && grid.ActiveRow.IsDataRow)
 {
      DataRow row = (grid.ActiveRow.ListObject as DataRowView).Row;
 }
```

Of course you could subst the ActiveRow of this example with every UltraGridRow where the IsDataRow property is true (beware of the SummaryRows and the OutlookGroupByRow)

Notice that if you bind to the DataSource a `List<CustomClass>` then the `ListObject` is able to return the single instance of the `CustomClass`

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, you can access the underlying `DataRow` via:

```
var myDataRow = ((DataRowView)myUltraGridRow.ListObject).Row;
```

given the precondition that your grid.DataSource object is a DataTable or DataSet.

Comment: In comparison to the accepted solution, this is especially useful if you are handling an event

Comment: For the VB affectionado, use: Dim myDataRow = CType(myUltraGridRow.ListObject, DataRowView).Row

Answer (score 0):

Use the [ListObject](http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2013.1/CLR4.0/?page=Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.v13.1~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridRow~ListObject.html) property of the UltraGridRow to get at the underlying data item.

Comment: Sorry, I did downvote by mistake and can't revert it!